# Validate a form with fields wrapped in another components in Aurelia

Tags: aurelia

I'm wondering if I can validate a form with input fields that are wrapped in another components.

Something like this:

```
<template>
    <require from="./inpWrap"></require>

      <form submit.delegate="submit()">
        <div class="form-group">
          <inp-wrap value.bind="firstName & validate"></inp-wrap>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </form>
</template>
```

Here's the full gist: [https://gist.run/?id=f94dd7502141f865468465ef25c9e5a1](https://gist.run/?id=3378e4dd19c1d39b22e6b737bfcfa34d)

Visually, in this example, the validation will run only on running the `.validate()` method (by clicking on the submit `button`) for the wrapped element.

Would it be possible to have the same validation behaviour for the component-wrapped elements?

Comment: Only if you bind the fields of the child component with the properties of the parent object that is being validated. Otherwise you'll need two separate validation sets.

Comment: Hmm, could you please provide an example?

Comment: I spent some time looking at your Gist Run and as best as I can tell, it should work.  A few minor fixes but they didn't fix the main problem. (1) In inpWrap.js, use `@bindable({ defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay }) value;` (2) In inpWrap.html, use `value.bind="value & validate"`.  This will ensure correct two-way binding.  Again, I don't know why validation is not working as it should.